# Sharing Fields to Text/Email/Notes on Multiple Lines

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently making an HMA Random Sampling app in Kotlin using Android Studio. The last bit that I am trying to add is a share function. I have created a basic working version, but can't seem to track down how to format it the way I'd like. Here is the code I'm currently working with:

```
val shareButton1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.shareButton)
        shareButton1.setOnClickListener {
            val contractNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.contractNumber)
            val conNumber = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contractNum)
            val desNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.desNumber)
            val desNum = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.desNum)
            val conNumber1 = conNumber.text.toString()
            val contractNumber1 = contractNumber.text.toString()
            val desNum1 = desNum.text.toString()
            val desNumber1 = desNumber.text.toString()
            val shareIntent = Intent()
            shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, conNumber1 + " " + contractNumber1 + " " + desNum1 + " " + desNumber1)
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"))
            }
```

I know this is probably  a very ugly way of doing this, but it is the only way I've found so far that somewhat works the way I need it to. My end goal is to have each set on their own line. For example `conNumber1` and `contractNumber1` would appear on the first line and `desNum1` and `desNumber1` would appear on the line below that, and so forth.

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated. I've been coming up with nothing on my searches for this.

Comment: So, you're trying to make a paragraph containing multiple values and you want to know how to push the content to next line? Add `\n` between two strings to break it into two lines as `"$conNumber1 $contractNumber1\n$desNum1 $desNumber1"`. If there will be multiple values, then you can use an array and loop to add the values to make a final string.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot. I didn't even think of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as @Lalit Fauzdar said add `\n` between two string
but careful add `\n` exact before string without space otherwise in new line first letter fill as space

Here is full code

```
val shareButton1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.shareButton)
    shareButton1.setOnClickListener {
        val contractNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.contractNumber)
        val conNumber = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contractNum)
        val desNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.desNumber)
        val desNum = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.desNum)
        val conNumber1 = conNumber.text.toString()
        val contractNumber1 = contractNumber.text.toString()
        val desNum1 = desNum.text.toString()
        val desNumber1 = desNumber.text.toString()
        val shareIntent = Intent()
        shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        shareIntent.type = "text/plain"
        shareIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "$conNumber1 \n$contractNumber1 \n$desNum1 \n$desNumber1"
        )
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"))
    }
```